# Dropping object between classes

Tags: java, android, object, loops

I have a stream of objects coming from a server to a client. There is a networking class within the client which handles taking these objects. There is then an activity which uses a get method to get this object as it is updated from the server (both client classes are constantly updating) the objects also have a position field within them which determines if they are 1 (first), 2 (middle), or 3 (end) of the current stream of data.

My problem is that using LogCat to print these I get the first object with position 1, within the networking class, but the activity misses this, and displays several 2's and one 3. So it is somehow loosing my first object.

My client network has the following relevant code:

```
public class ClientNetwork implements Runnable {

Drawring serverDraw;

public Drawring GetServerDraw(){
    Drawring drawPass = serverDraw;
    return drawPass;
}

public void resetpos(){
    serverDraw = null;
}
```

within public void run()

```
    while(true){

            while(true){

                serverDraw =(com.DrawTastic.Drawring) ois.readObject();

                test.add(serverDraw);


            }
        }
```

ClientActivity loops this:

```
try{
            Drawring fromNet = net.GetServerDraw();
            net.resetpos();
            int position = fromNet.getPos();
switch (position) {             
case 1: 
                try {
                    Log.d(null, "1st Position");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


                break;
            case 2:
                try {
                    Log.d(null, "2nd Position");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


                break;
            case 3:
                try {
                    Log.d(null, "3rd Position");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
}
catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d(null, e.toString());
        }
```